# Upside-down slideDown pushing stuff upwards

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I know that there were already similar questions on how to make an upside-down slideDown, but none of them was asking how to actually push all the stuff above the element upward.
What I need is that while the slideDown element is unwrapping upwards, the bottom part of this element (and also all the elements below) stays right where it is, and all the elements above move upwards.

I hope you get what I mean.

Is anything like this even possible??

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather CSS question. jQuery `slideDown` just animates `height` property, so if you want element to shrink upwards you can use following style combination:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}
.box .drop {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
}​
```

When element is positioned using CSS `bottom` property it will expand upwards.
You can look for working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/).

Comment: But the thing is that I need the .drop element to be rather relative because it must push elements above it upwards. I amended it a little here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/11/). The red element must move upwards!! .opener stays where it is and .drop unwraps upwards

Comment: For such cases it's better to use jQuery `animate` method. You can move content upwards using negative `margin-top` css property while simultaneously adding positive `paddingBottom`. This is basic solution, I've made demo to test this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/15/

Comment: thats a bit better but anyway I need the .opener to stay fixed at its position, in your example it moves down out of sight, I need the .content-above element to move up out of view..

Comment: What browser do you use? There might be jerky movements of `.opener` while animation is in process, you'll need to make more complicated markup to avoid this. I don't understand what is incorrect in my last example.

Comment: you know its absolutely essential that the .opener element HOLD STILL, NOT MOVE, STAYS FIXED..

Comment: So you just don't like jerky animation? Maybe you have scrollbars in viewport and see jump onclick? I fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/18/

Comment: no, no jerky animations, just smooth slide upwards of the content above.. I use IE, wait a sec. Ill try other browser. And Im sorry, English is my second language, i dont know how to make it clearer..

Comment: Great!! It seems ok!! But does it have to be with the space above?? I need the page without that space and scrollbar if necessary..

Comment: This is all could be done using CSS. 1) To avoid empty space before content remove `paddingTop` from `.page`. 2) To remove scrollbar from page add `body {overflow:hidden}` style rule. But that's not the part of original question :)

Comment: I removed the padding and margin and now it works perfectly!! here goes: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/22/)

Comment: wait a sec!! I just noticed that the scrollbar doesnt apper when it is needed. you know, I said I didnt want the srollbar when its not necessary, but I definitely need it after the .content-above moves up so that I can scroll up to the top of the page!!

Comment: Add callback when animation complete which will add scrollbars, remove negative margin and scrolls to the same positive offset, like: http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/27/ This is Q&A site, not coding guide, so try making your own experiments :)

Comment: great, tnx a lot!! I know, but I am not as quick as you and it seemed to me that it would be a lot more complicated to add the scrollbar back. Again, thanks:o)

Comment: I'm back. I'm still trying to figure out how to apply your example into my code. The thing is that I have totally different structure of divs. The .drop element is inside another element and above all this there are a few independent elements. I really dont know how to make it work.. I made a similar structure to my original here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/74/). Can you please help me with this for the last time?

Comment: You need to modify your HTML-sctructure for previous JS code, or update your JS code to custom structure. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/75/)

Comment: I cant modify my HTML-structure. It has to be the way it already is. i need to modify the JS code somehow, but I really have no idea how. I tried almost everything..

Comment: Sorry, I totally didnt notice.. yeah it looks ok. I will try to understand how it works and put it in my code. Ill let you know if I make it successfully. Thanks a lot again, I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I saw just the "Like" at the and of the line. It is like on Facebook so thats why I didnt notice the link below:o)

Comment: Oh, and isn't there some really independent solution without that .zzz kind of element. I might not have expressed exactly what I mean by independent. In my app there are several .box elements and each of the elements should behave like in your example but independently. And the worst part is that the number of the elements changes dependent on previous user's choice. So there might be 5, 7 or even 20 elements like that right after each other. It's almost impossible to make it this way since the structure would be different for each number of elements..

Comment: Of course I will use also identificators along with the classes in the selectors, but the problem is the code structure.. if it has to be different every time there is a different number of the .box-like elements..

Comment: I've used "zzz" just for demonstration purposes - of course you can change it. But if you want to make universal solution you'll have to think about unified HTML and some kind of universal script, otherwise I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Ok, I'll continue trying different solutions and hopefully I'll figure something out.. tnx..

Comment: try to repeat expanded state of last fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/94/) with pencil and paper. It's simply impossible to do without MOVING `.opener` buttons if MULTIPLE `.drop` blocks are present.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you're saying.. Of course, I would use an idetificator for each box so that they (the .drop elements) don't all roll up at the same time. But for me it essential to have some solution in which there no .zzz element that wraps all the other elements. I just need only JS or CSS solution that will work with the exactly same HTML structure like here: http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/96/ without any other elements added or removed.. Is that possible??

Comment: You said earlier that button should stay fixed in any condition, right? If you have several buttons which are pushing content upper it's just impossible to do. And the problem isn't in JavaScript - try to draw on paper expanded state for all buttons. And about structure - you can use jQuery `wrap` to change it on the fly.

Comment: Sorry I didn't modify the JS. Now I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/98/ I meant really independent elements, ie each .opener opens just the .drop in the .box where it is located, not the others. But once it did, it pushes upward only the stuff that is above that particular .drop element (including all the other .box elements that are before this particular element)..

Comment: Hi there, I eventually figured that out by myself. It's quite easy. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/116/. I used for loop, but in my original app it slides rather slowly..:o(

Comment: Cache variables like this `$(this).closest('.box')` to avoid constant search in DOM. This may significally improve performance. But I don't see animation in your example. But I'm glad you managed to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by caching variables?? you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/YDedH/117/ ?? I have this in my app but its still terribly slow.. There is no animation because clearly it doesn't work with the animation. Or did you come up with any other solution using animation and avoiding the .zzz element by any chance??

Comment: Yes I mean store variables which contains selectors search results. Until you'll provide something with exact structure and styles as in your app on jsfiddle it's hard to suggest how can you speed up this.

Comment: Nevermind, the structure of my real app is too complicated. It has hundreds of divs. I will use just .show() and .hide() and .fadeIn() for the contents. It works okay and pushes other elements upward too, so I guess I can do without sliding..